# Enter 5 in a master block field then only 5 record enter in detail block

Tags: oracleforms

I want to develop a form for stitching unit where a dress made with 3 or 4 or 5 pieces(trouser, shirt, sleeves, lace, scarf etc)

I want that if I enter in master block that dress is 4 pieces then only 4 record should enter in detail block

Comment: Sounds good, go ahead!

Answer (score 0):

You can create a master-detail form.

Then on the master-block you create a `post-insert` trigger.
In this trigger you can do the insert in the tabel of the detailed block for the number of records you need.

In the `key-commit` trigger, you do a commit and a requery of the detailed block.

```
commit_form;
go_block('detail_block');
do_key('execute_query');
```

Comment: Scenario change on every record it is not fixed that every time 5 pieces not fixed